# How to get ID when using new FormData(); javascript/codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I wasted 3 hours searching for the right syntax. How can i get the value of "prop_id" in javascript.

view -

```
  <input type="hidden" name="prop_id" value="<?=$prop_id_inserted?>">
```

javascript

```
function upload_docu_by_type(prop_id, input, filetype) {
var fd = new FormData();
var fileInputs = $("." + input);

$.each(fileInputs, function (i, fileInput) {
    if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
        $.each(fileInput.files, function (k, file) {
            fd.append('images[]', file);
        });
    }
});
fd.append("prop_id",input);
fd.append("file", filetype);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "applicant_w/upload_docu_by_type",
    data: fd,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {

    }
})
```

controller

```
public function upload_docu_by_type() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $F = array();
    $prop_id = sanitize($this->input->post('prop_id'));
    $file = sanitize($this->input->post('file'));
```

i want to get it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snipped, hope it work for you!

```
$("input[name='prop_id']").val();
```

Comment: i did  const prop_id_t = $("input[name='prop_id']").val();   fd.append("prop_id", prop_id_t);           it will send to controller?

Comment: No problem! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in JS:

```
document.getElementsByName("prop_id")[0].value;
```

```js
prop_id = document.getElementsByName("prop_id")[0].value;
console.log(prop_id);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="prop_id" value="test">
```